# Web application - is there any difference if load 1.000 images from a folder VS multiple folder?

Tags: php, linux, web-applications

Example you have 1.000 direct link to 1.000 images

- First case : 1.000 images placed in a folder ?
- Second case : 1.000 images placed in 1.000 difference folder ?

And we use linux OS,

So what case is better?
I think case one will faster than,
or anyone can tell me another conclusion => "It's same"
and plz explain your answer.

I think the importance point is there any difference if
I open 1.000 folder
VS load 1.000 direct link in difference folder from web page.
sorry I don't know for sure about the mechanism

Comment: This might be more of a serverfault question. The question appears to be more about IO than programming. But yes, it can make big differences how your directories are structured for non-trivial volumes. I can't tell you exactly _why_, but I have seen problems because of this in the wild.

Comment: If I understand your problem statement, Having to navigate 1000 folders to connect to one-and-only file inside is that folder, should be some tiny bit slower. Splitting up your 1000 files into ~20 folders (maybe even 100), could offer some savings. Most of these things are very OS/Hardware specific, and there won't be a general solution you can apply to everywhere. If this is really critical to you, then you'll need to set up a test framework and optimize for each instance (IMHO) . Good luck!